# Maven Test Dependencies with Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

We are using Spring, Maven and Java in our project. Sometimes we include dependencies to modules with scope "test". So these are only availabe in test, not in production. Unfortunately eclipse is not that intelligent. So when you use classes from those Test-Dependencies, you don't get compile errors. But when you later build it in some continuus integration environment via Maven (not compiling in eclipse) the correct workspace resolution gets used and it ends up with a compiler error. Class Not Found...

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376616

Comment: Just a suggestion: Switch to NetBeans it is that intelligent ;)

Comment: so its open since 2012 and will probably never get solved?? .... i have workd with netbeans too. and i dont like either of those IDEs. they are both not perfect...

Comment: This is due to the way that the m2e plugin brainwashes Eclipse to work with Maven projects.  The "only some part of the classpath applies here" is not part of the Eclipse mindset.    Learn to compile from the command line and do so often.  Use a CI engine to check commited code.

Comment: Also note that IntelliJ (and also Netbeans I belive) has a much better treatment of the Maven project model, so this does not apply.

Comment: well when your boss wants you to use eclipse, you have  to use eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Maven using: you define in pom.xml. you put on with hand.

how to do:

```
<!-- prod jar hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
<!-- testjar hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

you open to project path. you open window cmd with win+r short-key.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

(maven-3.5 add environment variables) if you see build success, nop.

we adding .jar with dependency. don't forget. (test or really .jar)

Comment: this won't help. it doesnt make a difference wether you use test or provided scope. and what you are doing is building via maven. which our continuous integration does too. but thats too late and i am to lazy to always say "run as maven build..." etc. i have auto-build activated in eclipse and search for a solution which works in eclipse. i want to tell eclipse that it should be aware of test scopes.

Comment: do you wanna build automatically maven?

Comment: i want to build / compile whenever i save in eclipse.

Comment: Do not copy works by others into your own. At most, you can quote small portions (with appropriate quote formatting and an attribution) to support your own answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing